# 新規質問画面のタグの説明が英語になっている

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

この画像のように右のタグの使い方の部分に未翻訳の部分があります。
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

未翻訳箇所がアップデートされましたのでお知らせいたします :)